# removing offset terms from a formula

Tags: r, formula

R has a handy tool for manipulating formulas, `update.formula()`.  This works nicely when you want to get something like "formula containing all terms in previous formula except `x`", e.g.

```
f1 <- z ~ a + b + c
(f2 <- update.formula(f1, . ~ . - c))
## z ~ a + b
```

However, this doesn't seem to work with offset terms:

```
f3 <- z ~ a + offset(b) 
update(f3, . ~ . - offset(b))
## z ~ a + offset(b)
```

I've dug down as far as `terms.formula`, which `?update.formula` references:

> [after substituting, ...] The result is then simplified *via* ‘terms.formula(simplify = TRUE)’.

```
terms.formula(z ~ a + offset(b) - offset(b), simplify=TRUE)
## z ~ a + offset(b)
```

(i.e., this doesn't seem to remove `offset(b)` ...)

I know I can hack up a solution either by using `deparse()` and text-processing, or by processing the formula recursively to remove the term I don't want, but these solutions are ugly and/or annoying to implement. Either enlightenment as to *why* this doesn't work, or a reasonably compact solution, would be great ...

Comment: a little more digging inside the code of `terms.formula` suggests that it **explicitly preserves the offset term**, although this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere as yet ...

Comment: Looking at `?offset` the documentation says `"There can be more than one offset in a model formula, but - is not supported for offset terms (and is equivalent to +)."`. Could this be the reason as your `offset()` terms aren't simplifying?

Comment: Not the most glamorous, but could you also try adding in an `offset(-b)` instead? Your formula won't look simplified but I think the effect should be the same. If you try `lm(mpg~cyl,data=mtcars);lm(mpg~cyl+offset(disp),data=mtcars);lm(mpg~cyl+offset(disp) + offset(-disp),data=mtcars);` You see the 1st and 3rd `lm()`s are the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1) Recursion** Recursively descend through the formula replacing `offset(...)` with `offset` and then remove `offset` using `update`.  No string manipulation is done and although it does require a number of lines of code it's still fairly short and does remove single and multiple `offset` terms.

If there are multiple offsets one can preserve some of them by setting `preserve` so, for example, if `preserve = 2` then the second offset is preserved and any others are removed.  The default is to preserve none, i.e. remove them all.

```
no.offset <- function(x, preserve = NULL) {
  k <- 0
  proc <- function(x) {
    if (length(x) == 1) return(x)
    if (x[[1]] == as.name("offset") && !((k<<-k+1) %in% preserve)) return(x[[1]])
    replace(x, -1, lapply(x[-1], proc))
  }
  update(proc(x), . ~ . - offset)
}

# tests

no.offset(z ~ a + offset(b))
## z ~ a

no.offset(z ~ a + offset(b) + offset(c))
## z ~ a
```

> Note that if you don't need the `preserve` argument then the line
>   initializing `k` can be omitted and the `if` simplified to:
>
> ```
> if (x[[1]] == as.name("offset")) return(x[[1]])
> ```

**2) terms**  this neither uses string manipulation directly nor recursion.  First get the `terms` object, zap its `offset` attribute and fix it using `fixFormulaObject` which we extract out of the guts of `terms.formula`. This could be made a bit less brittle by copying the source code of `fixFormulaObject` into your source and removing the `eval` line below.  `preserve` acts as in (1).

```
no.offset2 <- function(x, preserve = NULL) {
  tt <- terms(x)
  attr(tt, "offset") <- if (length(preserve)) attr(tt, "offset")[preserve]
  eval(body(terms.formula)[[2]]) # extract fixFormulaObject
  f <- fixFormulaObject(tt)
  environment(f) <- environment(x)
  f
}

# tests

no.offset2(z ~ a + offset(b))
## z ~ a

no.offset2(z ~ a + offset(b) + offset(c))
## z ~ a
```

> Note that if you don't need the `preserve` argument then the line that
>   zaps the offset attribute can be simplified to:
>
> ```
> attr(tt, "offset") <- NULL
> ```

Comment: Its not clear to me whether this is exactly the behaviour OP was looking for. There can be more than one offset term in a formula, and this method will remove all of them. I got the impression that OP wanted to remove only specified terms in the formula such as `offset(b)`, which would imply leaving `offset(c)` in place.  Perhaps @BenBolker can comment which behaviour is required?

Comment: Not sure that this is important but have added the feature to (1) and (2).

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be by design. But a simple workaround is

```
offset2 = offset
f3 <- z ~ a + offset2(b) 
update(f3, . ~ . - offset2(b))
# z ~ a
```

If you need the flexibility to accept formulae that *do* include `offset()`, for example if the formula is provided by a package user who may be unaware of the need to use `offset2` in place of `offset`, then we should also add a line to change any instances of `offset()` in the incoming formula:

```
f3 <- z ~ a + offset(b) 

f4 <- as.formula(gsub("offset\\(", "offset2(", deparse(f3)))
f4 <- update(f4, . ~ . - offset2(b))

# finally, just in case there are any references to offset2 remaining, we should revert them back to offset
f4 <- as.formula(gsub("offset2\\(", "offset(", deparse(f4)))
# z ~ a
```

Comment: this is fine for ben, but if the user is giving the formula to his package, say, then they would have to know about this caveat beforehand, right?

Comment: @rawr - yes if the intended use is a package where other users supply the formula, then this would be a problem.  Then it would be necessary to deparse the formula and replace any instance of offset with offset2 within Ben's package. Starts to get ugly then

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - I think that you can use the `[` method for class `terms` here:

```r
f1 <-   ~ x1 + offset(a) + offset(b) + h(x2)
f2 <- y ~ x1 + offset(a) + offset(b) + h(x2)

t1 <- terms(f1)
t2 <- terms(f2)

t1. <- t1[seq_along(labels(t1))]
t2. <- t2[seq_along(labels(t2))]

stopifnot(identical(formula(t1.),   ~ x1 + h(x2)),
          identical(formula(t2.), y ~ x1 + h(x2)))
```

The method is mentioned and aliased in `help("drop.terms")`, but the source code, `` stats:::`[.terms` ``, is more transparent about what is going on ...

I considered another possibility:

```r
tt <- terms(<formula>)
drop.terms(tt, dropx = integer(0L), keep.response = as.logical(attr(tt, "response")))
```

Unfortunately, `drop.terms` does not behave sensibly with zero-length `dropx`.  Probably worth a [bug report](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18563) ...

Comment: On the other hand, maybe `[.tarms` and `drop.terms` _should_ preserve offsets. Offsets are not terms, so there is no reason to expect them be discarded ...

Comment: Hence: https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18565