# replacing a symbol in a formula/expression

Tags: r, recursion, formula

Suppose I have a formula or other expression-like object

```r
ee <- a ~ b + c
```

and want to replace all instances of (for example) symbol `b` with `B`.  The hacky way to do this is with string substitution:

```r
(ee 
   |> deparse() 
   |> gsub(pattern = "\\<b\\>", replacement = "B") 
   |> as.formula()
)
```

This works (the result is `ee <- a ~ B + c`, as desired)

Arguably the better way to do this is to write a recursive function that checks whether a particular element is identical to the target and replaces it with the replacement if so, otherwise calls itself on the elements ... this is a huge pain.  Can someone suggest the *least* painful way to implement this (e.g. an incantation involving `rapply()`) ... ?

(Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40308944/removing-offset-terms-from-a-formula) about *removing* terms from a formula ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recursive function exists already: `substitute`.

```r
> do.call(substitute, list(ee, list(b = quote(B))))
a ~ B + c
```

Note that

```r
> substitute(ee, list(b = quote(B)))
ee
```

does not work because `substitute` is a special and does not evaluate its first argument:

```r
> typeof(substitute)
[1] "special"
```

Comment: thanks!  I think the similar problems I've tackled before ("delete terms of the form XXX"; "replace terms of the form `(f|g)` with `foo(f|g)`"; etc.) have been more complicated/required recursion, but this works perfectly for what I need to do right now ...

Comment: @BenBolker Related: https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18568

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more convenient interface, the following recursive function will do the trick, doesn't use string parsing, and isn't particularly painful

```r
replace_formula <- function(f, from, to, level = 1) {
  mc <- match.call()
  if(level > 1) f <- mc$f
  if(is.symbol(f) || is.function(f)) {
    if(identical(f, mc$from)) return(mc$to) else return(f)
  }
  as.call(lapply(as.list(f), function(x) {
    do.call(replace_formula, list(f = x, from = mc$from, to = mc$to, level + 1))
    }))
}
```

For example:

```r
replace_formula(a ~ b + c, from = b, to = B)
#> a ~ B + c

replace_formula(x ~ y + x|d, y, Y)
#> x ~ Y + x | d

my_formula <- y ~ cos(sin(a)) + a

replace_formula(my_formula, a, A)
#> y ~ cos(sin(A)) + A
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>